# Why data is not fetched from the observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular9

I've a service which makes a GET request to the server for fetching values.
Problem is occurring when I'm going to store the value in a variable in component.

**abc.service.ts**

```
public data: Category[] = [];
getPosts():Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.url + '/getAllExamCategory');
}
```

**def.component.ts**

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Category[];
dataSource: any;
columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'examCategoryName', 'isActive', 'Action'];

constructor(private adminCategory: AdminCategoryService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.adminCategory.getPosts().subscribe((reponse: Category[]) => {
      if(!reponse) {
        return;
      }
      this.ELEMENT_DATA = reponse;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Category>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

I'm not able to understand where am making the mistake. When I'm console logginf the `ELEMENT_DATA` variable to check it's length it's showing `undefined`.

Comment: Make sure your HTTP GET is returning a value successfully, `console.log(response);` would help.

Comment: yup am getting the reponse correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
getPosts():Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.url + '/getAllExamCategory')
       .pipe(map((reponse: any) => {
           console.log(reponse);
           return reponse;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: nope still having the same problem. Am able to get the response with the Observables but still in component getting length as ```undefined```.

Comment: Make sure that the spelling is correct ("reponse" and "response"). Also, only the length is getting undefined or "length of undefined" error?

Comment: actually the problem is solved it was the problem of the incoming JSON